# How to correlate input from a scanner to a string array in Java?

Tags: java

Here is what I have:

```
String[] LettersOne = new String[] {"A", "B", "C"};
String[] LettersTwo = new String[] {"D", "E", "F"};
String[] LettersThree = new String[] {"G", "H", "I"};
String[] LettersFive = new String[] {"J", "K", "L"};
String[] LettersSix = new String[] {"M", "N", "O"};
String[] LettersSeven = new String[] {"P", "Q", "R", "S"};
String[] LettersEight = new String[] {"T", "U", "V"};
String[] LettersNine = new String[] {"W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an uppercase letter: ");
String Letter = input.next();
```

What I want to do is have it so that whatever uppercase letter the user inputs, it will print out an assigned digit (which I have yet to do).

So if Letter is from something from LettersOne, then the system will print out an assigned number.

I'm new to programming so I'm still learning. Can this be done? How?

Comment: where is the assigned number?

Comment: @evanwong I haven't done that yet. I was just going to have the system print out an assigned number rather than directly assigning a number to a group of letters in a string array.

Comment: @evanwong in the String[] name, I would assume.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach will work but it is going to get pretty messy. I would instead suggest a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which allows you to associate your Strings with the Integers they map to.

You can start from scratch:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
myMap.put("A", 1);
myMap.put("B", 1);
myMap.put("C", 1);
myMap.put("D", 2);
// and so on
```

Alternatively, you can keep your arrays and do this:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String letter : LettersOne) { //agh, please use camel case!
    myMap.put(letter,1);
}
for(String letter : LettersTwo) { //agh, please use camel case!
    myMap.put(letter,2);
}
```

This allows you to store and associate individual letters to numbers. Because this is a learning experience, I will let you read the documentation to determine how to get the int out.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use your array structures, you can do it this way by having an array of your arrays. Here's an example transcript:

```
Enter an uppercase letter: X
Array number: 8; letter number 2
```

Here's the code:

```
String[] lettersOne = {"A", "B", "C"};
String[] lettersTwo = {"D", "E", "F"};
String[] lettersThree = {"G", "H", "I"};
String[] lettersFour = {"J", "K", "L"};
String[] lettersFive = {"M", "N", "O"};
String[] lettersSix = {"P", "Q", "R", "S"};
String[] lettersSeven = {"T", "U", "V"};
String[] lettersEight = {"W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
boolean found; // set to true once we've found the letter.

String[][] arrayOfArrays
      = {lettersOne, lettersTwo, lettersThree, lettersFour, 
          lettersFive, lettersSix, lettersSeven, lettersEight};

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an uppercase letter: ");
String letter = input.next();

found = false; // we haven't found it yet.

// loop through each of our arrays, and loop through each letter in each array.
for(int arrayNum = 0; (arrayNum < arrayOfArrays.length) && !found; arrayNum++) {
    // look through this array
    String[] thisArray = arrayOfArrays[arrayNum];
    for(int letterNum = 0; letterNum < thisArray.length; letterNum++) {
        String thisLetter = thisArray[letterNum];
        if (thisLetter.equalsIgnoreCase(letter)) {
            System.out.println("Array number: " + (arrayNum + 1) + "; letter number " + (letterNum+1));
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```